# Zooming in does not adapt date axis when using Julia's PlotlyJS in VSCode

Tags: plotly, julia

I am using `Plots.plot` along with PlotlyJS to display a time-series in the VSCode editor as follows:

```
using Plots
using PlotlyJS
...
plotlyjs()
plot = Plots.plot(dates, y)
display(plot)
```

So while the plot is "interactive" the dates do not adapt dynamically to the selected region. [Here](https://i.imgur.com/jADOfS2.mp4) is a quick video of the issue I'm facing. Ideally I want the dates to display in a nice way every time I am zooming in (or out), and not just being fixed once at initial creation.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: There are several github issues about this (dating back to 2018), and it stems from the ticks being calculated by `Plots` before being sent to the backends like `plotlyjs`, so the ticks end up being frozen. The fix is adding an argument `ticks=:native` to your plotting methods, but there is an open issue about this not working for dates when some argument is present. You should give it a try.

Comment: That worked! Spectacular. Make this an answer and I'll accept it, thanks!

Comment: Alright, I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is close to [Github issue 1382](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/1382). The issue was that `Plots` calculates the ticks before sending it to the backend via `plotlyjs()`, so the ticks end up "frozen" even if the backend is normally adaptive. They implemented an argument `ticks = :native` ([issue 1395](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/pull/1395)) to fix this, but be aware that it doesn't work well with some arguments, which is why it's not the default ([issue 1425](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/1425), [issue 3263](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/3263)).

An example of its usage from issue 1395:

```
using Plots; plotly()
plot(rand(10), ticks = :native)
```